# The irrationality of the sum of the reciprocal of number factorial

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the folowing sequence:
$$U_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$$
We have that this sequence converge to $l$ and:
$$Un.n!\le n!.l\le Un.n! + \frac{1}{n}$$
We have to prove that $l$ is irrational

I think that i should suppose that $l$ is rational and prove that by a contradiction but i can't see this contradiction, any help?

Edit: we have to use the inequality given above and no other methode.